# Connect to Zend Framework Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have some information on a Zend Controller that I want to show on a div on index.php sort as a menu, with title as button and the content as the content itself.
I tried to follow several tutorials, but did not get anywhere.
Can someone shed some light in how to call the Controller from index?

```
<?php

class TabController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function tabcontentAction(){

   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
   $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();


        $arr = array( array( Title => "Women", 
                  Content => date("H:i:s") . " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sem ligula, luctus et a
(...)
         )
         );

echo json_encode($arr);
}


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate method that returns the data:

```
protected function getMyData()
{
    $arr = array(
        array( 
            'Title' => "Women", 
            'Content' => date("H:i:s") . " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", 
        ),
     );
}
```

Then reference this method in any actions that need it:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $data = $this->getMyData();
    // now, do something with the @data
}

public function tabcontentAction()
{
    $data = $this->getMyData();
    // now, do something with the $data
}
```